# Как работает HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

Поправьте, если неверно - для объекта вычисляется хеш, помещается в такой вот ассоциативный массив, в нашем случае это HashSet. При возникновении коллизий, объект помещается в ту же ячейку в связный список. Но по какому принципу они распределяются? На первую пустую ячейку, или по какой-то логике? И почему поиск по хеш коду быстр? Как он их ищет?

Comment: странно, что у вас именно с HashSet  появился вопрос. есть массивы с уникальными индексами, есть базы данных с уникальными ключами... любое уникальное значение, коим является индекс массива, первичный ключ бд либо хеш-сумма дает возможность быстрого поиска из-за уникальности этого самого значения. когда вы в библиотеке книгу ищите, а они расставлены в алфавитном порядке, вы же понимаете за счет чего вы книгу быстрее находите?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Грубо говоря, хранилище HashSet - это просто массив. Хэш значения определяет по какому индексу в массиве будет храниться это значение. Соответственно и поиск - это просто обращение по индексу, поэтому и быстро.

Comment: А если у меня есть класс ```Person``` с единственный полем id, и для одного объекта его хеш будет равен, например, 63. Он поместится на 63 индекс?

Comment: Обычно ещё добавляют модуль по размеру массива, т.е. если у вас в HashSet массив размером 30, то 63%30 => элемент разместится под индексом 3

Comment: Прикольно) Пасиба. В википедии об этом не говорят. С:

Comment: @Anastasiya рекомендую "Структуры данных и алгоритмы" Роберта Лафоре. В ней в простой и доходчивой форме описано устройство хэш-таблиц и многое другое.

Comment: лучше всего описано в коде :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, это массив.
2. Нет, пустой элемент массива не ищет. Это метод открытой адресации разрешения коллизий. В HashSet применяется метод цепочек: в случае коллизии объект помещается в тот же элемент массива в односвязанный список. При достижении размера массива указанном в TREEIFY_THRESHOLD (8 по умолчанию) - уже не в односвязанный список, а в красно-черное бинарное дерево.
3. Какой будет индекс вычисляется на основании хеша и размера массива.
4. Ищет также, как вычисляется индекс. Т.е. мы не проходимся в поисках по всему массиву, а вчисляем индекс и сразу обращаемся по нему к нужному элементу.
5. Поэтому и быстро: O(1) при отсутствии коллизий.

Вообще, в HashSet все точно также, как в HashMap. Только в роли key вычтупает само value. Под капотом у HashSet мапа и работает.